# C# Unit Testing warn instead of fail

Tags: c#, unit-testing

When using Assert(...) if a logical test fails the unit test is aborted and the rest of the unit test isn't run.  Is there a way to get the logical test to fail but just provide a warning or something and still run the rest of the unit test?

An example of the context is I have a test that creates some students, teachers and classes, creates relationships, then places them into a database.  Then some SSIS packages are run on this database that takes the existing data and converts it into another database schema in another database.  The test then needs to check the new database for certain things like the correct number of rows, actions, etc.

Obviously other tests are deletes and mods, but all of them follow the same structure - create data in source db, run SSIS packages, verify data in target db.

Comment: can you explain your scenario better? It sounds like you might be doing something that I might advise against.

Comment: Updated with the context.  I know its best practice to make your unit tests green pass red fail, however in this case when there is a known bug that is of low priority, the order of Asserts could mean that it is hiding a bug of higher priority.

Comment: If you have a known bug, then you should have a failing test. If you want to ignore the bug, make a duplicate or similar test and remove the assert that is short circuiting the test run so you can test what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you are attempting to test too many things in a single test.

If a precondition isn't met, then presumably the rest of the test will not pass either. I'd prefer to end the test as soon as I know things aren't what I expect.

The concepts of unit testing are Red fail, Green pass. I know MSTest also allows for a yellow, but it isn't going to do what you want it to. You can do an Assert.Inconclusive to get a yellow light. I have used this when I worked on a code base that had a lot of integration tests that relied on specific database data. Rather than have the test fail, I started having the results be inconclusive. The code might have worked just fine, but the data was missing. And there was no reason to believe the data would always be there (they were not good tests IMO).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [**Gallio/MbUnit**](http://gallio.org), you can use [`Assert.Multiple`](http://gallio.org/api/html/M_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_Multiple.htm) to achieve what you want. It captures the failing assertions but does not stop the execution of the test immediately. All the failing assertions are collected and reported later at the end of the test.

```
[Test]
public void MultipleAssertSample()
{
   Assert.Multiple(() =>
   {
      Assert.Fail("Boum!");
      Assert.Fail("Paf!");
      Assert.Fail("Crash!");
   });
}
```

The test in the example above is obviously failing but what's insteresting is that the 3 failures are shown in the test report. The execution does not stop at the first failure.

Answer (score 2):

I know your question was asked several years ago. But recently (around 2017 or 2018) NUNIT 3 supports Warnings. You can embed a [boolean] test within an Assert.Warning as you would Assert.Fail. But instead of the single Assert line failing the whole test, the test running will log the Warning and continue on the the test.

Read about it here: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/Warnings.html

It behaves similarly to Multiple (listed by @Yann Trevin above, and Multiple is also available in NUnit 3.0). The cool difference though is on integration tests where having the flexibility of using stand-alone Assert.Warning commands shines. Contrast to a group Asserts within a Multiple instance. Once the Multiple assert has completed, the test may not continue.

Integration tests, especially those which can run for hours to, perhaps test how well a bunch of micros services all play together, are expensive to re-run. Also, if you happen to have multiple teams (external, internal, outurnal, infernal, and eternal) and timezones committing code virtually all the time, it may be challenging to get a new product to run a start-to-end integration test all the way to the end of its workflow once all the pieces are hosted together. (note - It's important to assemble teams with ample domain knowledge and at least enough software engineering knowledge to assemble solid "contracts" for how each API will be, and manage it well. Doing so should help alleviate the mismatches implied above.)

The simple black/white, pass/fail testing is absolutely correct for Unit testing.

But as systems become more abstract, layered upon service after service, agent after agent, the ability to know a systems robustness and reliability become more important. We already know the small blocks of code will work as intended; the Unit tests and code coverage tells us so. But when they must all run atop of someone else's infrastructure (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud), Unit testing isn't good enough.

Knowing how many times a service had to retry to come through, how much did a service cost, will the system meet SLA given certain loads? These are things Integration tests can help find out using the type of Assert you were asking about, @dnatoli.

Given the number of years since your question, you're almost certainly an expert by now.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've explained in the question, it is more of an acceptance test (than a unit test). Unit testing frameworks are designed to fail fast. That is why Assert behaves the way it does (and its a good thing.)

Coming back to your problem: You should take a look at using an acceptance testing framework like Fitnesse, which would support what you want i.e. show me the steps that failed but continue execution till the end.
However if you MUST use a unit-testing framework, use a collecting variable/parameter to simulate this behavior. e.g.

- Maintain a `List<string>` within the test
- append a descriptive error message for every failed step
- At the end of the test, assert that the collecting variable is empty

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to get a bit more meaningful failure report. I was comparing collections and used to get wrong number of elements - no idea what was the real reason for the failure. Unfortunately I ended up writing a comparison code manually - so checking all the conditions and then doing a single assert at the end with a good error message.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing is black and white - either you pass tests or not, either you are breaking logic or not, either your data in DB is correct or not (although unit testing with DB is no longer unit testing per se).

What are you going to do with the warning? Is that pass or fail? If it's pass then what's the point of the unit testing in this case? If it's fail.. well.. just fail then.

I suggest spending a little of time on figuring out what should be unit tested and how it should be unit tested. "Unit testing" is a cliche term used by many for very very different things.

Comment: The point is that your tests might be run as part of a CI/CD pipeline, and that in this case the test might sometimes fail but you don't want it to break the build and deployment.

Answer (score 0):

unit-testing might be more black and white than something like integration testing but if you were using a tool like speck flow then you might need the testing framework to give you a warning or assert inconclusive...

Why do some unit testing frameworks allow you to assert inconclusive if it's black and white?

Imagine that the test date of that you're passing in your unit test is created from a random data generator... Maybe you have several of these... for some data condition you are sure that it is a failure for another day to condition you might be unsure...

The point of a warning or a certain inconclusive is to tell the engineer to take a look at this corner case and add more code to try to catch it next time...

The assumption that your test will always be perfect or black and white I don't think it's correct I've run into too many cases and 15 years of testing where it's not passed or failed... it passes...fails... and I don't know yet... You got to think about the fact that when you fail a test it means that you know it failed...

False failures are really bad in automated tests... It creates a lot of noise... you're better off saying I don't know if you don't know that you are failing...